# why does the while loop not work?

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop

I'm creating a program that takes in the users grade(A-F), health(0-100) and economic output(0-100). I need a while loop for when the user inputs a value wrong e.g A for health. why does the loop keep repeating? how do I do this for the grade as well?

```
name = raw_input(' Enter your name: ')

grade = raw_input(' Enter your grade: ')


string_two = raw_input(' Enter your economic out put: ')
while string_two not in range (0,100):
    print 'please enter a value between 0 and 100.'
    string_two = raw_input(' Enter your economic out put: ')

string_one = raw_input(' Enter your health: ')
while string_one not in range (0,100):
    print 'please enter a value between 0 and 100.'
    string_one = raw_input(' Enter your health: ')


health == int(string_one)
economic_output == int(string_two)

if economic_output > 85:
    print name + ' you are exceptional! Welcome aboard!'
elif grade == 'A':
     print name + ' you are exceptional! Welcome aboard!'
elif economic_output > 60:
    if health > 60:
        if grade == 'B' or 'C':
           print 'Congatulations ' + name +'!' + ' Come aboard!'
else:
    print 'Sorry, ' + name + ' but you dont meet the criteria and cammot be permitted to board. '
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `while` loop keeps repeating because `raw_input` always returns a string object, regardless if you typed digits only or something else. `string_two not in range (0,100)` is always true because a string cannot be in any range of ints.

So what you can do. If I were you, I would define a function which would ask the user to enter something in a `while` loop until his input satisfies some pattern (just as you are trying to do in your code) and convert it to a specific type if necessary. There is a very useful tool to check a string for  matching some pattern, it is called regular expressions (RE).

```
import re

def inputAndValidate(prompt, pattern, convertFunc=str):
    result = raw_input(prompt)
    while re.match(pattern, result) is None:
        print 'Input pattern is "' + pattern + '". Please enter a string matching to it.'
        result = raw_input(prompt)
    return convertFunc(result)
```

Putting a piece of code being used several times to a function is a good practice. So here I defined a function called `inputAndValidate` with 2 mandatory parameters - a prompt to be displayed for user to let him understand what do you want from him, and the pattern to check his input. The third parameter is optional - it's a function which will be applied to the user input. By default, it's `str`, a function converting something to a string. User input is already a string, so this function will do nothing, but if we need an int, we'll pass `int` as the third parameter and get an int from the `inputAndValidate` function, and so on.

`re.match(pattern, string)` returns a match object if the string did match the pattern, and None if it didn't. See official [`re` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) for more information.

Usage of the function

```
name = inputAndValidate('Enter your name: ', r'.+') 
# This pattern means any string except empty one. Thus we ensure user will not enter an empty name.

grade = inputAndValidate('Enter your grade (A-F): ', r'[A-F]')
# This pattern means a string containing only one symbol in the A-F range (in the ASCII table).

economic_output = inputAndValidate('Enter your economic output (0-100): ', r'\d{1,3}', int)
# This pattern means a string containing from one to three digits. `int` passed to the third parameter means the result will be an int.

health = inputAndValidate('Enter your health (0-100): ', r'\d{1,3}', int)
# Same as the previous one.
```

`re` module documentation also contains information about the regular expressions language, it can help you understand the patterns I used.

Comment: Did you copy the function to your code as well? I mean a piece of code I wrote upper.

Comment: That's fixed the while loop but not the elif statement has stopped working, its only supposed to accept B or C but now accepts anything. how do I solve that?

Comment: Seems that the condition works not the way you wanted. It's `(grade == 'B') or ('C')` (operators priority). `'C'` is always converted to true (all strings are true when converted to bool implicitly except for empty one), so the whole condition is permanently true. `grade in ['B', 'C']` condition should work.

Comment: doesn't print congratulations but it doesn't print the else bit either?

Comment: Ah, yes. Your `else` works only for the very outer `if` and `elif`s. It doesn't for inner ones like that one checking the grade. To make `else` work properly you should put all these 3 conditions altogether with `and`, like `elif economic_output > 60 and health > 60 and grade in ['B', 'C']:`. If it looks too long, you can make a linebreak with backslash symbol. Or you can make a function checking everything and use it in `elif`

Comment: I'm making another more advanced program involving json files, can I email you about it?

Comment: I think yes, I have added my email to my profile @joespeed1

Comment: sent you an email